# How to find RequestConfigCallback sockettimeout from Junit test of RestClientBuilder?

Tags: java, junit

I have the following code in creating a RestClientBuilder where I set a custom socket time out:

```
public ConnectionBuilder() {
    RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpsHost(host,port,scheme)).setRequestConfigCallback( new RestClientBuilder.RequestConfigCallback() {
    
       @Override
        public Builder customizeRequestConfig(final Builder requestConfigBuilder) {
            return requestConfigBuilder.setSocketTimeout(CUSTOM_SOCKET_TIMEOUT); }});
    
    RestHighLevelClient restHighClient = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
    .... 

 }
```

I am trying to write a JUnit test to CONFIRM that the CUSTOM_SOCKET_TIMEOUT is the correct value BUT I am not sure how to retrieve it from RestHighLevelClient. I looked at the api and it is not clear to me how I can get that value...
Can someone help? Thanks